# Pulling data from mysql

Tags: mysql

1. I'm trying to pull data from 2 tables and when I add this in the $query, the results are all messed up when I click my link ex. /leads.php?contactstatus=Hot
2. How can I by default display all contactstatus types when I only have "Hot" "Warm" "Cold" as options in the table row contactstatus?

   ```
   <?
   mysql_connect ("xxxx","xxxx","xxxx") or die ('Error: ' .mysql_error());
   mysql_select_db ("xxxx");

   if(isset($_GET['contactstatus'])
   && in_array($_GET['contactstatus'], array('Hot', 'Warm', 'Cold'))){     
   $status = $_GET['contactstatus']; 
   } 
   else {      
   $status = ''; // what do I put here so by default users for all contactstatus types show in results 
   }  

    $query = "SELECT * FROM contacts,contacttodo WHERE contacts.contactstatus =    `'".$status."' OR contacttodo.type = 'Appointment'";`  

   $result=mysql_query($query);

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

   ?>
   ```

UPDATE:

This works:

```
<div class="nav">
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td>
<li><a href="/dbs/a.php?type=Appointment">Appointments</a></li> 
<li><a href="/dbs/a.php?contactstatus=Hot">Hot</a></li> 
<li><a href="/dbs/a.php?contactstatus=Warm">Warm</a></li> 
<li><a href="/dbs/a.php?contactstatus=Cold">Cold</a></li>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

$status = ''; 
$todotype = '';  

if(isset($_GET['contactstatus']) 
&& in_array($_GET['contactstatus'], array('Hot', 'Warm', 'Cold')))
{     
$status = $_GET['contactstatus'];     
 $query = "SELECT * FROM contacts,contacttodo,contactnotes WHERE contacts.ID = contacttodo.contacts_id = contactnotes.contacts_id AND contacts.contactstatus = '".$status."' ORDER BY contacts.firstname ASC"; 
}  

if(isset($_GET['type']) 
&& in_array($_GET['type'], array('Appointment', 'Email', 'Call')))
{     
$todotype = $_GET['type'];     
$query = "SELECT * FROM contacts,contacttodo,contactnotes WHERE contacts.ID = contacttodo.contacts_id = contactnotes.contacts_id AND contacttodo.type = '".$todotype."' ORDER BY contacts.firstname ASC"; 
} 
$result=mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

<div id="contact-results">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="contact-results"> 
<tr>
<td align="left" width="15%"><a href="/dbs/editcontact.php?ID=<? echo $row['ID']; ?>"><strong><? echo $row['firstname']; ?> <? echo $row['lastname']; ?></strong></a></td>
<td align="left" width="5%"><? echo $row['contactstatus']; ?></td>
<td align="left" width="15%"><? echo $row['contacttype']; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<?
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

By default how can I display all 'Hot' 'Warm' 'Cold' leads?

Comment: (Waits for someone to tell poster he didnt sanitize his queries).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
if(isset($_GET['contactstatus']) && in_array($_GET['contactstatus'], array('Hot', 'Warm', 'Cold')))
{
  $status = contacts.contactstatus = '".$_GET['contactstatus']."' ; 
} 
else 
{       
 $status = '0'; 
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM contacts,contacttodo WHERE contacttodo.id =  contacts.id AND (  ".$status." OR contacttodo.type = 'Appointment')";
```

The contacttodo.id =  contacts.id need to be updated for your structure

Comment: Did this and get invalid Mysql result: `$query = "SELECT * FROM contacts,contacttodo WHERE contacttodo.contacts_id = contacts.ID AND ( ".$status." OR contacttodo.type = 'Appointment')";`

Answer (score 0):

You've got no join condition linking the contacts and contacttodo tables, so you're getting a cross product. You'd need something like:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM contacts c
        INNER JOIN contacttodo ctd
            ON c.contact_id = ctd.contact_id /* Obviously, I guessed on the column names */
    WHERE c.contactstatus = '".$status."' 
        OR ctd.type = 'Appointment'
```

Comment: This give me an invalid Mysql result: `$query = "SELECT * FROM contacts INNER JOIN contacttodo ON contacts.ID = contacttodo.contacts_id WHERE contacts.contactstatus = '".$status."' OR contacttodo.type = 'Appointment'"; $result=mysql_query($query); while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>`

Comment: When I remove the `OR contacttodo.type = 'Appointment'` it seems to work okay but when I put that back in it says I have an invalid mysql result.

Comment: updated my code, can you direct me on how to make a default selection?

Answer (score 0):

I am updating my answer after your feedback about table definition.

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT t2.type FROM contacts t1, contacttodo t2 WHERE t1.id=t2.contacts_id AND (t1.contactstatus IN ('Hot', 'Warm', 'Cold') OR t2.type = 'Appointment')";
```

Comment: table1=contacts - ID, firstname, lastname, contactstatus and table2=contacttodo - id, contacts_id, reminder_date, type

Comment: Thanks, so I tried the following and it gave me an error saying invalid argument. I'm confused as to why this isn't working. All the table names and columns are correct. `$query = "SELECT DISTINCT contacttodo.type FROM contacts, contacttodo WHERE contacts.ID=contacttodo.contacts_id AND (contacts.contactstatus IN ('Hot', 'Warm', 'Cold') OR contacttoto.type = 'Appointment'";`

Comment: I would say, try the query in a sql terminal and see if you see your expected result and then try to find if there is any typo in your code.

Comment: My bad.. I was missing a parentheses. I have corrected answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET['contactstatus']) && in_array($_GET['contactstatus'], array('Hot', 'Warm', 'Cold'))){
    $status = "'" . $_GET['contactstatus'] . "'";
} else {
    $status = 'contact.contactstatus';
    // since contact.contactstatus ALWAYS equals contact.contactstatus
    // I wonder about the wisdom of doing it this way, but this is roughly how I do it anyway
}

$query = "SELECT *
    FROM contacts
        INNER JOIN contacttodo ON contacts.contact_id=contacttodo.contact_id
    WHERE contacts.contactstatus = " . $status . " OR contacttodo.type = 'Appointment'";
```

Also, takes a bit from Joe's answer about the join since putting the join condition in the WHERE clause will really screw up the result if you put in a condition that's always true.

Comment: get invalid mysql results using `$query = "SELECT * FROM contacts INNER JOIN contacttodo ON contacts.ID=contacttodo.contacts_id WHERE contacts.contactstatus = ". $status . " OR contacttodo.type = 'Appointment'";`